# Error 106 en Pascal

Tags: pascal

Hola estoy resolviendo el siguiente enunciado:
Leer desde un archivo números enteros Calcular y escribir el promedio de los elementos
positivos y distintos de cero que se encuentran entre dos negativos consecutivos.Ej
7 6 -1 0 2 4 -8 -7 3 1 -24 6 7 0 9 -8 --> debe escribir : 3 2 7,33
Mi programa se ejecuta correctamente y al final me aparece el error,tengo una idea de porque puede llegar a ser pero no se como solucionarlo.Creo que tiene que ver con el repeat que intenta seguir ejecutandose una vez terminado el archivo.Gracias
El error aparece asi:

> 3.0
>   2.0
>   8.0 Runtime error 106 at $0000000100000BFD   $0000000100000BFD
>
> [Proceso completado]

```
   begin
    prom := 0;
    suma := 0;
    cont := 0;

    assign(archivo,'/Users/tomasmatarazzo/programacion/ejercicio19.txt');
    reset(archivo);

    read(archivo,char1);
    read(archivo,char2);
    writeln(eof(archivo));

    while not eof(archivo) do
     begin
       if (char1 < 0) and (char2 >= 0) then
          begin
             repeat
             begin  
             suma := suma + char2;  
             if char2 > 0 then
               cont := cont + 1;                
             read(archivo,char2);
             end
             until (char2 < 0) or (eof(archivo));
          prom := suma/cont;
          writeln(prom:2:1);
          suma := 0;
          prom := 0;
          cont := 0;
          char1:= char2;
          read(archivo,char2); 
          end
       else
          char1 := char2; 
          read(archivo,char2);       
     end;

    close(archivo);
    end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa esta tabla de errores.
[Input-Output Errors](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Input-Output_Errors)

Segun la tabla, **"File not open for output"**. El error es debido a un `Write` o `WriteLn` sobre el fichero (si no estás ejecutando app. de consola).
Te recomiendo que ejecutes tu programa paso a paso y revises la línea en la que está fallando.
Es posible que el resultado debas redireccionarlo a otra salida (pantalla o un fichero diferente).